# Mouse hover not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I am working on some HTML5 pages where I used CSS hover property on a hyperlink. I want that when click on some titles as shown in image the hover color is get fix and right now when we hover on other titles hove are working and if we click other their color will be fix and first one will white and specially all the time hover are working.

In my case everything works fine, when I click on title color is fixed but the hover to other titles are not working I used JavaScript's onclick event to fix hover color.

[image: Title Hover Problem]

```
<a href="#Main-Services-Page" id="Services-TechnicalSupport-Link-Button" onClick="ShowTechnicalSupportDiv();FixHeadercolorTechnicalSupportBlue();FixHeadercolorSmartCloudServicesWhite();FixHeadercolorInteriorDesignServicesWhite();FixHeadercolorUiCustomizationWhite();ServicesProductEnqBlueMiddleIcon()"> 
   Technical Support 
<p class="SubTitleHeadings" style="font-size:13px; line-height:15px"> We serve customers problems </p>
<p class="SubTitleHeadings" style="font-size:13px; line-height:1px"> on technical issues</p>            
</a>

 function FixHeadercolorTechnicalSupportBlue()
 {
   var col=document.getElementById("Services-TechnicalSupport-Link-Button");
   col.style.color="#66ffff";
 }
```

Comment: Please share you code

Comment: I add code for 1 link i think it will helpful.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using this function `onclick` use `onmouseover`. How can you expect the hover will work like this:

```
onmouseover="FixHeadercolorTechnicalSupportBlue();"
```

Comment: I also try mouseover, mouseout, mouseenter, mouseleave events they works good but I want that when click 1 title blue color fix that shows it must be selected. and when at that same time we hover to other title hover (blue color) working. in my case in onclick color is fixed but later that mouse hover not working I want to refresh page. like that mouse hover works once until i clicked title.

Comment: Incase Yes then you have to apply hover effect forcefully with `!important` property. because once you use `style.color` it applied inline. so therefore it may block `hover effects`

Comment: Thank you sir. just single word "!important" solved my troubling problem.

Comment: Happy to help you @Vir

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Services-TechnicalSupport-Link-Button").hover(function(){
  //When mouse is enter to Services-TechnicalSupport-Link-Button
},function(){
  //When mouse the leave Services-TechnicalSupport-Link-Button
});
```

Comment: yes i try this with javascript also with jquery its same with hover in css but how to fix color that shows it will be selected.